# How to resolve runtime error when trying to execute Element.Click command

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am attempting to run a macro that clicks on an IE webpage to download a file. When running my macro I encounter `Runtime Error 91: Object variable  or with block variable not set` I removed my url string for security purposes

The line that is highlighted is `Element.Click` How can I resolve this

```
Sub Playthissub()

     Call Scrape("myurl") '' change the website here and execute this sub.

End Sub

 Sub Scrape(url As String)

     Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
     Dim Document As HTMLDocument
     Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection
     Dim Element As HTMLGenericElement

     Set Browser = New InternetExplorerMedium
     Browser.Visible = True
     Browser.Navigate url

     Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
         DoEvents
     Loop
     Set Document = Browser.Document

     Set Elements = Document.getElementsByTagName("navPipeline")

     Element.Click

     Browser.Quit
 End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIK I doubt 'navPipeline` is a tag?  If  `Set Elements = Document.getElementsByTagName("navPipeline")`  is reffering to correct button.`Element` is not being set. May use `Elements(0).Click` or  `Elements(X).Click`. if it is possible then it is even better to refer the button with `Set Element = Document.getElementsByID("IDSomething")` directly  then
use `Element.Click`

Comment: @AhmedAU i am now getting `Object doesn't support this property or method` I changed my code to your suggestion

Comment: As commented earlier i doubt you are referring to correct button? could you share `url` of the site . or at least source Html of that part of the site.

Comment: `navPipeline` isn't an HTML element name, so what is it?  A class name? An Id?  It would help to show the relevant HTML you're working with.

Comment: @Tim Williams I will post as much of the HTML code as possible by tomorrow. I do not have access to my work computer at the moment

Comment: ^^ Thanks. We need to see the html in order to debug. Remember to use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html - not images.